# How to search and sort large time series data using ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, time-series

I have time series data that I want to search with ElasticSearch and display the results on a time line. Data source generates 10^9 events/month and I want to search last 6 months. I estimate about 50-70% of data is actually duplicates that occur in different time. In relational database I'd have two tables, something like this

**tblEvents**

```
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id |      desc (~200 UTF-16 chars)       |
+----+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | this is full-text searchable entry1 |
|  2 | foo                                 |
|  3 | bar                                 |
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

**tblEventsTime**

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | id_ev |   time    |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |     1 | 123456787 |
|  2 |     1 | 123456788 |
|  3 |     2 | 123456789 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

And my query would look something like this

```
select *
from tblEvents e inner join tblEventsTime et
    on e.id == et.ev_id
where 
    e.desc like 'foo' and
    et.time between X and Y
order by et.time desc
take 100
```

How would I do this with ElasticSearch?

Comment: First you create time-based indices: depending on the shard size/number of nodes and maybe other variable, you create one index per day or per week, or per month. This index will be a flattened representation of your relational DB tables. Meaning, you find a way to move the `time` part to the document with id `1`. Use Curator to manage these time based indices and an aliases to search them.

Comment: This is what's happening just now. But it takes way too much space and becomes pricey to run. As I seem to have many duplicates I thought of some sort of normalisation.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: essentially `desc` is the same, or in other words everything in the event is the same - it just happened at different time.

Comment: And why don't you keep those times in the same document, as an array for example?

Comment: This is what I am testing at the minute. I have an event index and and event_time index. I use the first one for full text search and the second one to resolve actual occurrence of the events on a time line. I am not sure this is the best approach, as I need to make couple of requests and also merge results - effectively a client side join.